# MSVC list symbols inside a static .lib file

Tags: c++, static-libraries

Is there a command line tool that I can use (or comes with) Visual Studio that will print the names of the symbols inside a C++ static lib file in a simple and easy to parse format?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is the `dumpbin.exe` tool included with MSVC, which you can use.

For example to display all information about the library:

```
dumpbin.exe /ALL yourlib.lib
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) for reference.

Comment: Also, consider the symbols and out flag for dumpbin: `dumpbin /symbols yourlib.lib /out:symbols.txt`